# How do I fix this error : expected an identifier.dart

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Riddhish's App")),
        
        body:
    );
  }
}
```

Can someone help meto solve this issue. I am doing this for flutter.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be specific and post the exact error that you are getting and also what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Just add something to your `body` and make sure to add `,` in the ed of the line, if you don't want to add anything, just add `null`:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Riddhish's App")),
        
        body: /* Add a widget here*/ ,
    );
  }
}
```

or:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Riddhish's App")),
        
        body: null,
    );
  }
}
```